# Testing Object Instantiation in Rails Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controllers

(In RSpec) I am testing that an object in my controller is getting instantiated:

CONTROLLER:

```
stripe_params = StripeParams.new(params)
```

TEST:

```
it "creates a new params instance" do
  get :message, params
  StripeParams.should_receive(:new).with(params)
end
```

... However, this is giving me the following test error:

expected: 1 time
received: 0 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to work expectation prior to run the code:

```
it "creates a new params instance" do
  StripeParams.should_receive(:new).with(params) 
  get :message, params
end
```